# Calculate initial velocity

Tags: physics

If I have the equation $y'' = -g -by'$, I know that a rock was thrown straight up from a specific height h, and hit the ground at time t, how do I calculate its initial velocity?

I don't understand what I use for y'' in order to figure this out?

Comment: How do $y,g,b$ relate to $h, t$?

Comment: b is the air resistance, and it is known. g is the gravitational force, and y is the vertical position.

Comment: So $y(0)=h$, and $y(t)=0$ sort of thing?

Comment: You're going to have to consider upwards motion and downwards motion separately since the equations of motion are different. Therefore you will need to calculate the maximum height and the time taken to reach this, ad well as the time to descend...